# Can't install gnome extension after upgade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell-extension

After upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, some Gnome extensions can't work. I try to delete and re-install them through Chrome/Firefox, but the download action can't start as expected.
How to debug the issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade from Ubuntu 19.04? If not, then your issues may be the result of "skipping" versions. You can read up on it [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes#:%7E:text=If%20you%20wish%20to%20%27skip,then%20upgrade%2017.04%20to%2017.10.). In which case you should backup your data and do a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and it should work properly.

If you're interested in why "skipping" versions is a problem, read the first answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading).

Comment: Upgraded from 18.04 LTS. It should not be a problem as the second answer~
I used another solution to make the extensions work:
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions.
But some extension not work as expected or can't disabled~

Comment: I do think the issues resulting from "skipping" versions can be unpredictable. I also recently upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and Nautilus couldn't mount my android device nor connect to servers. A fresh install of 20.04 fixed everything.

Comment: Yes, I do the same, just backup then run a fresh install~